# How to display a value in the window using tkinter?

Tags: python, random, tkinter

What can I do to get the result in the interface instead of the terminal in the given code? I want the `random.choice` result to appear in the table.

```
import random
import tkinter, sys
from tkinter import *

lista = ['Kamil Winnicki', 'Wiktor Jasiński', 'Adam Turowski', 'Arek Major', 
         'Dominik Piechotka', 'Jakub Laskowski', 'Jakub Materak', 'Kacper Kołodziejski', 
         'Kamil Stankiewicz', 'Konrad Nosek', 'Krzysiek Wawszczak', 'Andrzej Oplebsiak', 
         'Miłosz Tarucin', 'Paweł Pawłowski', 'Mateusz Lebioda']

def koniec():
    sys.exit()

def losowanie():
    print(random.choice(lista))

main = tkinter.Tk()

#nagłowek
te = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Lista 1T:')
te.pack()

#Wyswietla liste 1T
listbox = Listbox(main)
listbox.insert(1, '1. Mateusz Lebioda', '2. Jakub Laskowski', '3. Kamil Winnicki', 
                  '4. Wiktor Jasiński', '5. Adam Turowski', '6. Arek Major', 
                  '7. Dominik Piechotka', '8. Jakub Materak', '9. Kacper Kołodziejski', 
                  '10. Kamil Stankiewicz', '11. Konrad Nosek', '12. Krzysiek Wawszczak', 
                  '13. Andrzej Oplebsiak', '14. Miłosz Tarucin', '15. Paweł Pawłowski')
listbox.pack()
#losuje
y = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'losuj', command = losowanie)
y.pack()

#wyjscie z aplikacji
x = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'Zakoncz', command = koniec)
x.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want it to appear on the same frame? Clear everything in the frame and then just print the random choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to show a dialog with the choice.

```
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

def losowanie():
    messagebox.showinfo(message=random.choice(lista))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you need to append the result of `random.choice(lista)` to the listbox element, this can be achieved by the following code:

```
def losowanie():
    listbox.insert(END, str(listbox.size() + 1) + ". " + random.choice(lista))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan-Dev suggested you could do that but you can also get rid of the function

This will do what you intend to, but without the function `losowaine`:

```
y = tkinter.Button(main, text = 'losuj', command = lambda : 
                listbox.insert(END, str(listbox.size() + 1) + ". " + random.choice(lista)))
```

This below code will just insert the random choice at the end of the table (with function `losowanie`)

```
 def losowanie():
    listbox.insert(END, (random.choice(lista)))
```